# getMac npm angular cli

Tags: mac-address, angular-cli-v8

I have install this:

```
npm install --save getmac
```

and insert in my home.components.ts this code

```
import getMAC, { isMAC } from 'getmac';
```

and in ngOnInit this code text:

```
console.log(getMAC());
```

The Console Error is:

```
core.js:5873 ERROR Error: failed to get the MAC address
at getMAC (index.js:37)
at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (home.component.ts:15)
at callHook (core.js:3937)
at callHooks (core.js:3901)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:3842)
at refreshView (core.js:11795)
at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
at refreshView (core.js:11800)
at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac?activeTab=readme

> Get the MAC address of the current machine you are on.
>
> This library will **not run in web browsers / on the client-side / in**
> **webpack / in browserify / in angular / in react / in jQuery / in HTML.**
> It will only run on Node.js environments, which the web browser is
> not.